# Specify custom DNS server

Tags: configuration, exit-relays, dns

Is it possible to specify a custom DNS server so that the targeted website can see it? Otherwise `ExitNodes {us}` is useless if the website is geoblocking by DNS flag which is not shown clearly most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

The Tor client doesn't perform DNS requests, Exits which you use do.

If you specify `ExitNodes {us}` then an Exit in the which Tor thinks is in the US will resolve the address for you.

If your application is making DNS requests, it is leaking and potentially deanonymizing you and you should reconfigure it to properly utilise Tor or use an application which is capable of doing so.